# CSS transform: translateX( to the right );

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I want to make a particle system for my home page. Blue little circular dots should go from left to right and then reapear in the left so that it makes a loop.
[Image of particles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oegp.png)

The code below will generate 150 dots that all have different properties as speed color and size and will apear at random positions when loading the page. Either by looping the animation or by adding new dots I want to continue the animation infinitely.

```
// ========== JAVASCRIPT ==========
function Dot(){
    var colors = [
        "#313146",
        "#36364f",
        "#3d3d5c",
        "#404066"
    ];
    var speed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 2;

    this.obj = document.createElement("div");
    this.obj.classList.add("dot");
    this.obj.style.top = (window.innerHeight * Math.random()) + 'px'; // random Y-position after page load
    this.obj.style.left = (window.innerWidth * Math.random()) + 'px'; // random X-position after page load
    this.size = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 4; // random size
    this.obj.style.height =  this.size + 'px';
    this.obj.style.width = this.size + 'px';
    this.obj.style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)]; // random color
    this.obj.style.animation = `move ${speed}s linear`; // start animation
    document.body.appendChild(this.obj);

    setTimeout(del, speed*1000, this.obj); // THIS FUNCTION SHOULD BE REMOVED IF ANIMATION GETS A LOOP
    function del(element) {
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    };
};

for(var i = 0 ; i < 151 ; i++ ){ // creating 150 dots
    new Dot();
};

// ========== CSS ==========

.dot {
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
}

@keyframes move {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0vw);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(100vw);
    }
}
```

My problem is that as the dots apear with random positions, and all of them get a `transform: translateX(100vw);`, they will move out of the screen for a while before being deleted or reapeared at the beginning. My second image shows in red where the dot is moving to, and where it should move to.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F81FE.png)

What I tried allready:

1.
JS:
`` this.obj.style.animation = `move ${speed}s linear infinite`; `` added infinite and deleted the code that deletes the dots.

CSS:

```
@keyframes move {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0vw);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(right); 
    }
}
```

<= Does not exist, and couldn't find working code equal to this idea.
This would have been a solution.

2.
Adding a second animation with dots coming from the left when other ones where deleted.
Ended in a gap between the 150 dots of the first animation and the incoming dots of the second animation.

Is there any other possibility of moving the dots from left to right with different properties?

best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are setting the position with JS so you can know exactly where each element will appear and use this information to adjust the animation.

Here is a basic example to illustrate:

```css
.dot {
  background: blue;
  position:fixed;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  left:var(--x,0px);
  animation:move 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0vw);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(calc(100vw - var(--x,0px)));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="dot" style="top:10px;--x:80px;"></div>

<div class="dot" style="top:20px;--x:150px;"></div>

<div class="dot" style="top:100px;--x:350px;"></div>
```

The variable `--x` will define left and will get substracted from the `100vw`

---

For better support and since you are using JS, you can get rid of `calc()` and  CSS variables. Simply do a small calculation to find the value of transform.

Here is an example where I am using jQuery for simplicity but you can easily make it a JS-only code:

```js
$('.dot').each(function() {
  $(this).css('transform','translateX('+ ($(window).width() - parseInt($(this).css('left')))+'px)');
});
```

```css
.dot {
  background: blue;
  position:fixed;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  animation:move 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dot" style="top:10px;left:80px;"></div>

<div class="dot" style="top:20px;left:150px;"></div>

<div class="dot" style="top:100px;left:350px;"></div>
```

Worth to note that you need to update the value on window resize

---

Another idea to keep the loop effect is to have the same position and the same animation for all and you adjust the delay to simulate the different position:

```css
.dot {
  background: blue;
  position:fixed;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  left:0;
  animation:move 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100vw);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="dot" style="top:10px;animation-delay:-1s;"></div>

<div class="dot" style="top:20px;animation-delay:-0.1s;animation-duration:1s"></div>

<div class="dot" style="top:100px;animation-delay:-0.5s;animation-duration:4s"></div>
```

The calculation is easy. If the animation duration is `D` then a delay of `-D/2` will place the element in the center intially. `-D*0.1` will place the image at `10%` and so on.

Comment: In pure CSS I don't quite understand how to add the 100% keyframe which is missing in the css. How would that be done? And also the dots don't reapear before the left border. How could this be changed?

Comment: @Covy all the trick is there, you don't need to add it to the animation. Add to the element and the animation will by default use it for the 100% if it's missing

Comment: I added ```this.obj.style.transform = `transform: translateX(${window.innerWidth-this.obj.style.left})`;``` and removed the function that removes the dots. But as I expected the dots don't move. (The 100% keyframe as I thought?)

Comment: @Covy check well the code, you have an extra transform and you need to add pixel at the end `this.obj.style.transform = 'translateX(${window.innerWidth-parseInt(this.obj.style.left)}px)'`

Comment: Ok so now everything works as in your exemple. But the dots reapear at their first position and not before the left border. To fix this I changed the CSS to ```@keyframes slide { 0% { transform: translateX(-100vw); } }``` and added ```this.obj.style.animationDelay = `-${speed/2}s`;```so that the animation didn't start behind the screen. Result of this: All the dots first apear in the left half of the window and then the animation loops as it should. Here you can see what I mean: https://streamable.com/4zi8v

Comment: @Covy check the update, added a better and easier way at the end

Comment: With your updated exemple the dots can't have different speeds. Is there any possibility of changing this? I will probably need different animations for different speeds right?

Comment: @Covy they can have different speed by adding a different duration for each one like you are already doing. Each element will have a duration and a delay based on its duration to find the position

Comment: I finally made it. To perfectly fir my question: "having different properties as speed color..." and so on, I would change your answer a little bit. I will still give you a check mark as it helped me a lot together with the comments. Thanks a lot for helping!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) to animate your particles. Take a look at the following example. I've added the `move` method to the particle which is called from the animation loop and changing the particle's position. It also checks if the particle has reached the end of the screen and resets its position to `-10` in this case.

```js
function Dot(){
    var colors = [
        "yellow",
        "red",
        "green",
        "black"
    ];
    this.x = window.innerWidth * Math.random();
    this.speed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 2;
    this.obj = document.createElement("div");
    this.obj.classList.add("dot");
    this.obj.style.position = "fixed";
    this.obj.style.top = (window.innerHeight * Math.random()) + 'px'; 
    this.obj.style.left = this.x + 'px'; 
    this.size = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 4; // random size
    this.obj.style.height =  this.size + 'px';
    this.obj.style.width = this.size + 'px';
    this.obj.style.background = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)]; // random color
    document.body.appendChild(this.obj);
    this.move = function() {
      this.x += this.speed;
      if (this.x > window.innerWidth) {
        this.x = -10;
      }
      this.obj.style.left = this.x + 'px';
    };
};

var dots = Array.apply(null, Array(150)).map(a => new Dot());

requestAnimationFrame(paint);

function paint() {
  requestAnimationFrame(paint);
  for (dot of dots) {
    dot.move();
  }
}
```

```css
.dot {
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

I also recommend you this [great book](https://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-4-particle-systems/) about particle systems. It shows how to implement forces, interaction and complex behavior.

Comment: As I can see in the code snippet it works perfectly, I still prefer the css-animation solution. Thanks for helping!